# django1.10の_meta.get_field_by_nameについて

Tags: django, python3

## 前提

django1.10を使っています。
python3.5.1でやっています。

## やりたいこと

django1.10では、_meta.get_field_by_nameが使えなくなったのですが、
_meta.get_field_by_nameと同じことができるものってあるんですか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

django 1.10の[Model `_meta` APIについてのドキュメント](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/ref/models/meta/)によると、`Options.get_field(name)`か`Options.get_fields()`を使って書き換えられる、とのことです。

具体的に`_meta.get_field_by_name(name)`についてどうすればよいかも書いてあったので (まだ英語のままですが) 引用します。

> Assuming you have a model named `MyModel`, the following substitutions can be made to convert your code to the new API:
>
> (中略)
>
> - `MyModel._meta.get_field_by_name(name)` returns a tuple of these four
>     values with the following replacements:
>
>   - `field` can be found by `MyModel._meta.get_field(name)`
>   - `model` can be found through the `model` attribute on the field.
>   - `direct` can be found by: `not field.auto_created or field.concrete`
>       The `auto_created` check excludes all “forward” and “reverse” relations that are created by Django, but this also includes `AutoField` and `OneToOneField` on proxy models. We avoid filtering out these attributes using the `concrete` attribute.
>   - `m2m` can be found through the `many_to_many` attribute on the field.

ただし、新しいAPIを使う形にリファクタリングする方が良いだろう、とも書いてあります。
より詳しくはドキュメントを参考にしてください。

- [Model `_meta` API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/ja/1.10/ref/models/meta/) -- Django 1.10 Documentation (ja)

Comment: `self._meta.get_fields(***)`とすると、`TypeError: Invalid argument for include_parents: kind`と出てしまいます。

Comment: @sizumita `get_field(field_name)`ではなく`get_fields()`をご使用なのでしょうか。後者はフィールド名の引数をとりません。

Comment: 'get_field(***)'にすると、'TypeError: 'CharField' object is not iterable'となってしまうんです。

Comment: @sizumita そのエラーは`get_field(field_name)`の行で発生しているのでしょうか？

Comment: はい。'.get_field(＊＊＊)'のところです。

Comment: TypeError を見る限り、get_fieldに渡してるのが **CharFieldオブジェクト**  なのがエラーの原因です。get_fieldに渡すべきは **文字列** です。 

get_field("filed_name")